# The value of primeng's slider doesn't updates

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I've a simple component with a slider and two buttons:

**app.component.html**

```
<p-slider [(ngModel)]="val" [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1"></p-slider>

<button pButton type="button" label="Next" (click)="next()"></button>
<button pButton type="button" label="Reset" (click)="reset()"class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SliderService } from './slider.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  val: number;

  next() {
    this.val++;
  }

  reset() {
    this.val = 0;
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I click on `Next` button, it does nothing. It should increment the sliders value.

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-rouffe?file=app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the value of `val` is `undefined`. You should initialize your sliders value to some number like `val: number = 0`. When you call your `next()` method, it increments the value `undefined`, which gives you `NAN`.

Updated app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SliderService } from './slider.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  val: number = 0; // Initialize your val's value

  next() {
    this.val++;
  }

  reset() {
    this.val = 0;
  }
}
```

The updated, working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-b4niys?file=app/app.component.ts).